# How to build a personal watercraft lift using a simple lever

Tags: outdoor

A personal watercraft lift sits in about 1 to 2 ft. of water. The platform or rails are about 4 ft. high. Enough for the waves to go under the craft and keep it dry and safe until it is launched.

Most lifts are expensive ($3000), are made of aluminum and use pulleys and cables. Lifts are either vertical or of a cantilever system. My plan is to simply make a lever system. I would drive to the base, hook up the craft to winch and crank it onto the 2 rails until the lever becomes horizontal.

- The craft is 500 lbs, 4 x 10 ft.
- it is balanced at about 4 ft depending on gas
- it will be made in two section, base with fulcrum and rails with winch
- lift at rest will have 2 legs at front with no more than 30 lbs of load
- material will mostly be pressure treated wood with about 20 or so rubber wheels for the craft to glide on
- rail are 16 ft with pivot point at 10 ft
- at rest, the craft would be balanced mostly on pivot (+30 lbs on legs)

So does this make sense?

What should I do different?

And, will this work?

[image]

Comment: The underside of the boat is wedge shaped, no? It's going to pry your rails apart, so you need to tie the rails together. A straight line between the rails will interfere with the boat, though. I suppose you could put the tie well under water so that the boat clears it as it enters your system, but without frequent ties the boards between that tie and your fulcrum again are wedged open. Calls for strong rails or curved frames that bridge the rails without touching the boat.

Comment: Will work on a diagram once I figure how to post. When I did a Google search for Mechanical lifts that use this method, came up with nothing. Even AI could not help me. I plan on using 2x6 and galvanized braces for the rails. That should clear the transom.

Comment: In general concept, I think it would work. I agree with @popham that you'll need to brace the support rails together. I'd recommend AL instead of galvanized steel - I think it would last longer. I'm not saying you shouldn't do this, but I think you'll get a very good appreciation of why the lifts work the way they do and cost what they do. :D Also, consider how you're going to get it back off the lift...

Comment: Added picture, let me know if I left something out. To launch Seadoo , I plan on just pushing it off.  Rollers will make this easy.

Comment: I think a fixed ramp, only one winch, and just yank the boat up another foot is a lot easier and simpler than adding a fulcrum and a second winch that achieves basically the same thing ... gets the back of the boat up another foot.

Comment: The basic problem I see with this is that it is extremely specific to a particular boat. Make significant changes to the boat that affect length or center of gravity and you have to change the lift. Borrow someone else's boat and this doesn't work so well. Have a friend visit with their own boat and this doesn't work so well. etc. Whereas a simple ramp + winch or traditional lift will work with any size/type/style of boat up the maximum capacity (length, width, weight).

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with the traditional approach of running a trailer down a boat ramp...?

Comment: The "boat" is a Seadoo Spark . It would be built for this WPC only. There is no beach in Georgean Bay for me to build a ramp. It would be offshore in one to two ft. water.

Comment: looks doable ... it may be simpler to winch the boat onto a floating deck

Comment: Thought about that but the cost is still above $3k and the storm waves would require serious anchoring. I  should be able to make this for under $400. To me, this is a simple plan. It is just that I cannot seem to find any examples out there. So the reason I posted was to get new ideas on how I can improve my design.

Comment: Admittedly, my first thought is the cartoon anvil or safe dropped on the other end when you pull on to the ramp.... The pivoting rails are not weightless, so the total load is more than illustrated (which seems to be based on the weight of only the vessel, ignoring a substantial bit of hardware 16 feet long and hopefully strong enough to hold the vessel.)

Comment: yes, 2x6 have weight, so x2 4ft would be maybe 10 to 15 lbs so that is why I ignored it.   And winch is rated at 1200lbs "pulling".

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can work. It seems overly complicated, though. Some considerations:

- You'll need to keep the rails from spreading. This means a U-shaped cross member like most boat trailers have at several points.
- You'll need to keep the whole thing from *racking*. This means more diagonal bracing than you've drawn, both on the platform rails and the fulcrum structure.
- You'll have to keep it from *twisting*. That's perhaps harder than the first two points with a relatively flat platform. Wood tends to be soft in a marine environment.
- You'll have to figure out how to have the winch attachment at hand when you pull up to the ramp (or how you'll hold the craft as you get off, etc.).
- The impact of the craft dropping onto the support rest will be orders of magnitude more than the 30 lbs. you assume unless you're *really* careful with how you winch it up. There's a dynamic imbalance at play when it starts to tilt over the top and weight shifts past the fulcrum.
- You're going to have to push the craft out from the rest position by hand, which means the opposite of the last point comes into play. How much do you like your teeth? Can you keep bystanders from getting whacked in the face?
- You need a very stable base at the lake bed. In my considerable experience with boat lifts, this can be challenging.

A simple roller ramp, possibly with a level top section, and with no other moving parts seems like a smarter strategy to me. If this was a good plan you'd see old boathouses using it.

Comment: Thanks, you made some good points that I will consider. If it was in a boathouse , I would have more options. This will be freestanding. The part about 30lbs, that is normally what you would have on the tongue when on a trailer.

Comment: Not true. The dynamic loads on a trailer are also much greater. You seem to be consistently failing to consider impact and motion.